# numpy savetxt is not adding comma delimiter

Tags: python, numpy

numpy savetxt is not adding comma delimiter

I have an array with the following contents:

```
3.880631596916139792e-01
6.835074831218364011e-01
4.604322858429276133e-01
3.494236368132551673e-01
7.142120448019100287e-01
2.579415438181463793e-01
8.230159985476581674e-01
7.342531681855216652e-01
3.196536650498674748e-01
7.444435819161493439e-01
```

And I save it as follows:

```
 np.savetxt('x.train.1.txt',XTraining, delimiter=',')
```

However when I look into the txt file, there is no commas.

Comment: Can you post the exact code you are using in context?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I guess the default use case is to store a list of lists, that's why you either need to treat it as list of only one list:

```
np.savetxt('x.train.1.txt',[XTraining], delimiter=',')
```

Or put the comma instead of the newlines (note: this adds a trailing comma)

```
np.savetxt('x.train.1.txt',XTraining, newline=',')
```

Comment: maybe adding the reason why OP's code doesn't work will be beneficial for future readers

Comment: @kmario23, just added some text around the solution

Comment: I think your second solution adds a trailing comma.

Comment: @PaulPanzer: thanks, this is true, I've added a note in the answer

Answer (score 3):

If you want them on separate lines and comma separated

```
np.savetxt('x.train.1.txt', XTraining[None, :], delimiter=',\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a format, e.g. fmt='%d,', with the comma(s) in it as you want in the output.

```
np.savetxt('x.train.1.txt',XTraining, fmt='%d,')
```

Also works with multiple columns

```
np.savetxt('x.train.1.txt',XTraining, fmt='%s, %f, %f,')
```