# numpy.savetxt doesn't recognize delimiter and newline parameters

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, save

I am solving a differential equation and store the result coordinates, velocities and accelerations for each time step in a numpy array. At the very end, I reshape the array into a matrix with seven columns (t, x, vx, ax, y, vy, ay). Then, I want to save the matrix into a text file using numpy's savetxt function, columns separated by tabs, and rows written in separate lines. The code I use is the following:

```
res.reshape(n+1, 7)
np.savetxt('result.txt', res, delimiter='\t', newline='\r\n')
```

What I get from this is that every member of the matrix is printed in a separate line like so:

```
0.0000e+00
5.0000e-01
0.0000e+00
-1.0000e+00
0.0000e+00
1.6300e+00
0.0000e+00
0.0000e+00
4.9583e-01
-8.3167e-02
-9.9167e-01
```

and so on. Based on a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068144/numpy-savetxt-is-not-adding-comma-delimiter) I tried modifying the savetxt arguments like this:

```
np.savetxt('result.txt', [res], delimiter='\t', newline='\r\n')
```

The result is that now the members are separated by tabs, but everything is written in one single line:

```
0.0000e+00  5.0000e-01  0.0000e+00  -1.0000e+00 0.0000e+00  1.6300e+00  0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00  4.9583e-01  -8.3167e-02 -9.9167e-01
```

and so on. What should I do to get a file that looks like this:

```
0.0000e+00  5.0000e-01  0.0000e+00  -1.0000e+00 0.0000e+00  1.6300e+00  0.0000e+00  
0.0000e+00  4.9583e-01  -8.3167e-02 -9.9167e-01 1.3556e-01  1.6164e+00  -2.7112e-01 
1.0000e-01  4.7953e-01  -1.7773e-01 -9.3289e-01 2.9409e-01  1.5640e+00  -5.7213e-01
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first solution should do it, just you make a mall mistake. The `reshape` of your result is not an inplace operation. `res` is an array and after your reshaping you have to assign it into a variable.

`res = res.reshape(n+1,7)`

Otherwise, you should be able to do

`np.savetxt('result.txt', res.reshape(n+1,7), delimiter='\t', newline='\r\n')`

Also, you can do a nicer reshaping by using `reshape(-1,7)` where it'll create 7 columns and it'll adjust the amount of rows needed.

You can also add a header line to the file (would highly recomend it)

```
header = ('t', 'x', 'vx', 'ax', 'y', 'vy', 'ay')
np.savetxt('result.txt', res.reshape(n+1,7), delimiter='\t', newline='\r\n', header=header
```